# How can I retrieve these specified fields from the ads campaign from the facebook Marketing api?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So far I have retrieved everything except for the Delivery, Results, Cost per results, Desktop App Installs and Mobile App Installs from the facebook ad manager as seen below.

[ads manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFC2c.png)

There are no explicit fields in the api documentation nor in the files themselves that could give me the info on these fields.

Here is my code, I can retrieve all the other fields using this

```
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebookads.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebookads.adobjects.adset import AdSet
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights

fields = {
    Campaign.Field.name,
    Campaign.Field.objective,
    # Campaign.Field.
}
params = {
    'date_preset' : 'last_90d',
    Campaign.Field.effective_status: [
        'ACTIVE',
        'PAUSED',
    ],
}

sets_fields = {
    AdSet.Field.name,
    AdSet.Field.end_time,
}

insight_params = {
    'date_preset': 'last_90d',
}

insight_fields = {
    AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
    AdsInsights.Field.reach,
    AdsInsights.Field.spend,
    AdsInsights.Field.total_action_value,
}

account = AdAccount('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
campaigns = account.get_campaigns(fields=fields, params=params)
# print campaigns
adcampaign = Campaign('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
adsets = adcampaign.get_ad_sets(fields=sets_fields)
# print adsets
adinsights = adcampaign.get_insights(params=insight_params, fields=insight_fields)
print adinsights
```

Is there a way to retrieve the other fields using the facebook api?